# Scrape table fields from html with specific class

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

So I want to build a simple **scraper** for google shopping and I encountered some problems.

This is the html text from my request(to `https://www.google.es/shopping/product/7541391777504770249/online`)  where I'm trying to query the highlighted div class `sh-osd__total-price` inside the div class `sh-osd__offer-row` :
[image: html text]

My code is currently:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests import get
url = 'https://www.google.es/shopping/product/7541391777504770249/online'
response = get(url)

html_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

r = html_soup.findAll('tr', {'class': 'sh-osd__offer-row'}) #Returns empty
print(r)
r = html_soup.findAll('tr', {'class': 'sh-osd__total-price'}) #Returns empty
print(r)
```

Where both r are empty, beatiful soup doesn't find anything.

Is there any way to find these two div classes with beautiful soup?

Comment: The URL for me is empty, when I open it in Firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add user agent into the headers:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests import get
url = 'https://www.google.es/shopping/product/7541391777504770249/online'
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.88 Safari/537.36'} #<-- added line

response = get(url, headers=headers) #<--- include here

html_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

r = html_soup.find_all('tr', {'class': 'sh-osd__offer-row'}) #Returns empty
print(r)
r = html_soup.findAll('tr', {'class': 'sh-osd__total-price'}) #Returns empty
print(r)
```

But, since it's a `<table>` tag, you can use pandas (it uses beautifulsoup under the hood), but does the hard work for you. It will return a list of all elements that are `<table>`s as dataframes

```
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.google.es/shopping/product/7541391777504770249/online'
dfs = pd.read_html(url)

print(dfs[-1])
```

**Output:**

```
print(dfs[-1])
                     Sellers Seller Rating  ...              Base Price Total Price
0               One Fragance     No rating  ...  £30.95 +£8.76 delivery      £39.71
1                       eBay     No rating  ...                  £46.81      £46.81
2              Carethy.co.uk     No rating  ...  £34.46 +£3.99 delivery      £38.45
3               fruugo.co.uk     No rating  ...  £36.95 +£9.30 delivery      £46.25
4  cosmeticsmegastore.com/gb     No rating  ...  £36.95 +£9.30 delivery      £46.25
5           Perfumes Club UK     No rating  ...  £30.39 +£5.99 delivery      £36.38

[6 rows x 5 columns]
```

Comment: Wow! thank you very much for the detailed answer. Didn't knew I could that with pandas, really useful!

Comment: Yup. Anytime I see a table tag I just go with pandas. Saves a ton of coding time